# A $G_{\delta}$ subset of a Baire space is Baire

Tags: general-topology, baire-category, the-baire-space

I have been seeing this fact used a lot but have not been able to find a proper proof justifying it. Would anyone be able to outline one?

Comment: This is false, by the way.  In a metrizable space every closed subset is a $G_{\delta}$-set, so this would imply that every closed subset of a metrizable Baire space is Baire.  This sounds good but turns out to be wrong: a standard counterexample is to remove from $\mathbb{R}^2$ the irrational points on the $x$-axis.  It is true that every **dense** $G_{\delta}$-set in a Baire space is again Baire.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of a countable intersection of dense open sets (i.e a $G_{\delta}$ set ) is a countable union of closed sets with empty interior, i.e. of the first Baire category. Therefore a $G_{\delta}$ subset of a Baire space is of the second Baire category, i.e. itself a Baire space.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. However am still having some trouble seeing this, would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: I will respectfully leave you to invest more than 3 minutes to think about it. Try thinking about it a little bit more. I am following the definitions almost word by word. Read the definitions, see where they come in.

Comment: So is the complement of a first category set always a second category set?

Comment: First of all, this answer is for dense $G_{\delta}$'s only (which is what makes the statement correct so perhaps correctly interprets what the OP meant to ask).  But it only shows that a dense $G_{\delta}$ in a Baire space is of the second category.  The definition of a Baire space is that every nonempty open subset is a subset of the second category.

Comment: @uniquesolution As written, your solution is not correct.  Even your definition of $G_\delta$ set as being a countable intersection of dense open sets is incorrect.